# While removing python3 from linux ubuntu, terminal and many other software uninstalled. Now pressed ctrl+alt+f2(something) and now I am stuck

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

On the black and white interface I tried to write sudo apt install python3-all, sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and sudo apt-get --fix-missing install, and many more but everytime error is occuring and at the end showing,"unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"
If I follow the steps told and wrote run sudo apt-get update.... Then it's saying at the end, "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones instead. "

I search on the internet to find out the solution of this problem... And here in stackoverflow.com many solutions were given and I tried to follow them, but the same output came. Some errors and unable to fetch some archives and more.

Comment: Try asking in the Ubuntu stackexchange.